# Converting tags in OpenStreetMap (OSM) files to attribution in shapefiles?

Tags: python, shapefile, openstreetmap, geoconverter

I've downloaded the street data from OpenStreetMap (OSM). I'm looking for speed limit attribution and OSM seems to be the only source for my jurisdiction (Ontario, Canada). The problem is, the speed is stored as a 'tag' and when I download the .osm file and convert it to .shp using [geoconverter](http://geoconverter.hsr.ch/), it stores all the tags into a single attribute. For example, the field "other_tags" wil contain: "hgv"=>"no","lanes"=>"3","maxspeed"=>"50","old_ref"=>"48","oneway"=>"yes","surface"=>"asphalt"

I just want *maxspeed* and maybe *lanes*

I have next to no programming skills. With that in mind, does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Your question had an [tag:arcgis] tag but you make no mention of using that platform in your question body.  Can you [edit] your question to explain how ArcGIS (presumably for Desktop?) relates to your question, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geoconverter seems to be using GDAL but unfortunately you can't edit it's configuration.

GDAL OSM driver is using a configuration file "osmconf.ini" for setting which tags will be converted into normal attributes http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html. You must install GDAL locally and edit the osmconf.ini file which by default has these settings for lines:

```
[lines]
# common attributes
osm_id=yes
osm_version=no
osm_timestamp=no
osm_uid=no
osm_user=no
osm_changeset=no

# keys to report as OGR fields
attributes=name,highway,waterway,aerialway,barrier,man_made
```

All you need to do is to add maxpeed into the list of attributes, and to learn how to use ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html.